# Should Escape immediately close an application?

Tags: interaction-design, user-behavior, user-expectation, desktop-application, keyboard-shortcuts

My question comes directly from the fact that the popular RetroArch emulator uses Escape key to quit the whole application and, moreover, it's apparently a big [source of drama](https://github.com/libretro/RetroArch/issues/2670#issuecomment-183717148) for some.

It personally perplexes me as barring some really obscure examples every game and app I used did not close itself when you press escape (with the notable exception of Game Maker games which have/had it by default and it has to be manually disabled). I actually thought it's common knowledge and an established UX pattern for escape to only pause whatever you're currently doing (and instant quit being reserved to alt+f4) but looking around I don't think I can find anything on that.

So, **is immediately closing an application when the user presses escape good, bad or neutral UX?** I am specifically asking about desktop applications, not web apps (unless they are run in a context of a self-contained desktop application like [NW.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js), which makes them not really a web application anymore)

Comment: keepass, the password database, minimizes on ESC. In that context, a quick way to obscure information is logical. For RetroArch, I don't see any benefit in that mapping but I do see a strong negative: mistapping F1 with ESC has irreversible consequences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conventions are there to make life easier to users. **User expectation is both for patterns they expect and patterns they don't expect**.

If a rule or convention is skipped there has to be a good reason to do so.

So in the case you describe and only with that information, in my opinion, **it is not a good idea to**:

- Ignore alt+f4, you didn't mention it but if the case is this then it ignores user-expectation
- **Use a key combination which is not expected to do a certain action**
- **Quit an application with a single key**. Because it could be pressed accidentally, adding a two key combination adds some strain to the Quit action

Comment: +1 for **Quit an application with a single key**, this alone would already be enough to object the idea

Comment: When I highlight text in the terminal and accidentally use `Ctrl` + `C` instead of `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `C` to copy the text, I accidentally close the application. So sometimes two keys to close an application isn't good either.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about good or bad it's only about preferences.

since being a gamer myself **Esc** key always helped me in navigating easily inside games, but I never came across any game in my life which completely closed on **Esc** keypress. Also you can find the use of **Esc** keys in web-apps, for ex. closing a modal window on **Esc** keypress.

I don't know about RetroArch emulator(sorry for that) whats it's context and reason behind closing the app on **Esc** key press.

So for me it's only a matter of choice how you want to use **Esc** key. but I would never close my app on **Esc** keypress.